# How to solve inequality for $\det A $ and $\operatorname{trace} A$ if $\operatorname{radius}(A) \le 1$ and A is 2x2.

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is amplification factor. It has two eigenvalues (could be equal). I need spectral radius of A to be $\le 1$ and if it is equal to $1$ than both eigenvalues don't equal to $1$ simultaniously.

We have that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 = A_1 \pm \sqrt{A_1^2 - A_2}$. Where $A_1=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{trace}(A), A_2 = \det A.$

I sampled solution and get the following plot (blue area is where we get into complex domain):

```
points = [];
group = [];
im = [];

for a1 = -1.1:0.05:1.1
    for a2 = -1.1:0.05:1.1
        if a1^2-a2 < 0
            im = [im; a1 a2];
        end
        points = [points; a1 a2];
        if norm(a1+sqrt(a1^2-a2))<=1 && norm(a1-sqrt(a1^2-a2))<= 1
           group = [group;0];
        else
           group = [group;1];
        end
    end
end

gscatter(points(:,1), points(:,2), group, 'gr');
hold on
scatter(im(:,1), im(:,2), 'blue');
legend('good', 'bad');
xlabel('A1');
ylabel('A2');
```

[image]

But how can i solve this inequalities?

---

I provide bounds here just to make the question clearer, but i would like to understand how these bounds were calculated.

$$
\color{purple}{\boxed{
\begin{align}
-\frac{A_2+1}{2} \le A_1 \le \frac{A_2+1}{2} &\ \mbox{if}\ A_2 < 1\\
-1 < A_1 < 1 &\ \mbox{if}\ A_2 = 1
\end{align}}}
$$

---

My approach:

We can't allow both evalues be equal 1. So first we consider two cases when $\lambda_2 < 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$

- $\lambda_2 < 1$  means that $A_2 = \det A = \lambda_1\lambda_2 < 1$

$$ 1 \ge |A_1 \pm \sqrt{A_1^2-A_2}| $$
$$-1-A_1 \le \pm \sqrt{A_1^2-A_2} \le 1-A_1$$
We can split it into two equations:
$$
\begin{align}
-(1+2A_1+A_1^2)\le -A_1^2+A_2\\
A_1^2-A_2\le 1-2A_1+A_1^2
\end{align}
$$
Now cancel $A_1^2$ and rearrange
$$
\begin{align}
-2A_1\le 1+A_2\\
2A_1\le 1+A_2
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{equation}\boxed{{1+A_2 \over 2} \le A_1\le {1+A_2 \over 2}}\label{eq:caseone}\tag{1}\end{equation}$$

- $\lambda_2 = 1$ and so, we can't allow $A_1$ be equal to 1.

Substituting $A_2 = 1$ into $\ref{eq:caseone}$ we have that 
$$\boxed{-1 < A_1 < 1}.$$

> I think i have messed up with the cases.

Comment: I see the inequality for spectral radius of $A$ is at most one, but how do you intend your request "to solve inequality" for $\det A$ and $trace A$?  Things would be clearer if you separate (1) what information is known, and (2) what information (inequalities?) you want to deduce.  At present these items are in a jumble.

Comment: Do you men that you want sharp bounds on $\det A$ and $\tr A$ given that the spectral radius is $\leq 1$ (and the condition that not both eigenvalues are $1$)? Also, the plot suggests you're only considering real matrices $A$---is this correct?

Comment: @Travis yes, the matrix is real, and i want bounds on $\det A, \operatorname{tr} A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The caracteristic equation of  $2 \times 2$ matrix is $$\lambda^2-\mbox{trace}(A)\lambda +\mbox{det}(A)=0$$

so, if$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues we have $\mbox{trace}(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and $\mbox{det}(A)=\lambda_1 \lambda_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues $\lambda_a$, so $$|\det A| = |\lambda_1 \lambda_2| = |\lambda_1| |\lambda_2| \leq 1 \cdot 1 = 1 ,$$ and thus $-1 \leq \det A \leq 1$. On the other hand, we can find specific matrices achieving both of the endpoint values $\pm 1$ (do so!), so these bounds are sharp.

On the other hand, the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, so
$$|\textrm{tr}\, A| = |\lambda_1 + \lambda_2| = \cdots . $$
Can you finish the analysis of the trace on your own?

Comment: The thing is that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are connected by [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), so i'm not sure i can just say that $\operatorname{tr}A < 2.$

Comment: For any particular $A$ that's true, but we're making a general statement about $2 \times 2$ matrices satisfying some conditions, and we can construct a matrix with any eigenvalues we like: For example, any two given numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2}$.

Comment: I see you've modified your original question to ask about specific inequalities *relating* $\det A, \textrm{tr} A$, which is a question of a different flavor. This is not consistent with your answer to my question in the comments on the original question!

Comment: Sorry for this missunderstanding. I thought that the picture makes it clear which bounds do i want.